# How can I annotate labels to images automatically?

Tags: computer-vision, multilabel-classification, object-detection

I have 80 classes, for each class, there are 100 images. I want to label all images for object detection.
For this task I have downloaded the LabelIMG tool but it's taking a long time to do it. How can I automate labeling?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic image annotation has its limitations. It's basically another already trained machine learning model that's doing the annotation for you.

Keep in mind that automatic annotation also requires another step in between, which is selecting elements with low prediction confidence and review them by hand. These are the most problematic elements when you use an automatic tool to label images and almost always require manual review.

[image: Automated]

*Image source and suggested reading:* https://medium.com/anolytics/what-are-the-limitations-of-automatic-image-annotation-vs-manual-a8ff7edb3152